# How to implement Objective-C callback handler in SWIFT?

Tags: objective-c, callback, swift

The objective c code seems like this:

```
- (void)signInAccountWithUserName:(NSString *)userName
                         password:(NSString *)password
                       completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionBlock
{
    // Log into the account with `userName` and `password`...
    // BOOL loginSuccessful = [LoginManager contrivedLoginMethod];

    // Notice that we are passing a BOOL back to the completion block.
    if (completionBlock != nil) completionBlock(loginSuccessful);
}
```

and this method usage is:

```
[self signInAccountWithUserName:@"Bob"
                       password:@"BobsPassword"
                     completion:^(BOOL success) {
                         if (success) {
                             [self displayBalance];
                         } else {
                             // Could not log in. Display alert to user.
                         }
                     }];
```

How can I implement it in Swift? What is the equivalent implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func signInAccount(username:NSString!, password:NSString!, completionBlock:((Bool)->())?) {
    if completionBlock {
        completionBlock!(true)
    }
}

signInAccount("Bob", "BobPassword") {
    (var success) in
    println("\(success)")
};

signInAccount("Bob", "BobPassword", nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would implement methods with callbacks in swift.

```
func signInAccountWithUsername(userName:String!, password: String!, completion: (Bool) -> Void){

  completion(false)
}



signInAccountWithUsername("Swift", "secret swift", {
    success in

    if success{
      println("Success")
    }else{
      println("Failure")
    }
})
```