# Translating Objective-C function call to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

This is what I have so far...

```
func rightButtonItemsInRevealTableViewCell(revealTableViewCell: SWRevealTableViewCell!, handler:((Bool) -> (NSArray))!) {

    var item1: SWCellButtonItem = itemWithTitle("Delete", {
        (var success) in
            println("\(success)")
        }
    });

    item1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    item1.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    item1.width = 75;

    return item1;
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011992/how-to-implement-objective-c-callback-handler-in-swift) that is somewhat helpful but I am still getting some errors.

This is the original Objective-C code...

```
- (NSArray*)rightButtonItemsInRevealTableViewCell:(SWRevealTableViewCell *)revealTableViewCell {

    SWCellButtonItem *item1 = [SWCellButtonItem itemWithTitle:@"Delete" handler:^(SWCellButtonItem *item, SWRevealTableViewCell *cell)
    {
        NSLog( @"Delete");
    }];

    item1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    item1.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    item1.width = 75;

    return @[item1];
}
```

This is in the header declaration

```
+ (instancetype)itemWithTitle:(NSString*)title handler:(BOOL(^)(SWCellButtonItem *item, SWRevealTableViewCell* cell))handler;
```

And the definition in .m file

```
+ (instancetype)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title handler:(BOOL(^)(SWCellButtonItem *, SWRevealTableViewCell *))handler 
{
    return [[SWCellButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:nil handler:handler];
}
```

Comment: A down vote with no comment isn't really helpful

Comment: I think in Swift there is no "instancetype" anymore.

Comment: And why do you have a "handler"-parameter in your swift code? it doesn't even exist in your objective-c code?

Comment: Well, there is an init method, and the thing at the end beginning with "^" is a block. I've seen some question around here asking how translate block in Swift. Good search.

Comment: @beef, the handler is in the .h and .m file and thought I needed to include that as part of the call.

Comment: I looked up how to handle the "^" block and that's part of the reason I included the handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func rightButtonItemsInRevealTableViewCell(revealTableViewCell : UITableViewCell) -> NSArray {

    var item1 : SWCellButtonItem = SWCellButtonItem("Delete", handler: ((item : SWCellButtonItem, cell : SWRevealTableViewCell) -> (Void) in {
            NSLog("delete")
        }))
    item1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    item1.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    item1.width = 75
    return [item1];
}
```

I hope I didn't forget anything, try it out!

Comment: Maybe that's also helpful for you: https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/
Swift is pretty cool, don't give up :)

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is

```
let item : SWCellButtonItem = SWCellButtonItem(title:"Delete", handler:{(item:SWCellButtonItem!, cell:SWRevealTableViewCell!)->(Bool) in

        println("Delete handler")
        return false
    } )
```

Comment: You say "*the right solution is...*" but you don't explain **how** or **why** it's better than the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28885309/1364007) which presumably you are saying is wrong. Can you expand on your answer?

Comment: Previous answer forgot title and handler's closure returns (Bool) instead of (Void), also item and cell are not optional!

Comment: Aha. That makes more sense now.